# How can I find touchscreen hardware information?

Tags: touch-screen

I have a Canon ScanFront that is no longer useful as a scanner. The device contains a single board computer running some flavor of Linux (**uname -mrs** returns **Linux 3.10.87-cei.10_32-ltsi i686**).

Normally, the scanner boots to a GUI with touchscreen functionality. After I extracted the PCB from the scanner and booted it, the startup process failed with an error reporting that the scanner was not found and kicked me out to a BASH-like shell logged in as root (which is a good thing).

When I boot off a USB drive to Ubuntu, I can get to GNOME but the touchscreen is not detected. Returning back to the original distro (glad I didn't overwrite the SD card), I can run both lspci and lsusb but I don't see the touchscreen.

```
root@serialnumber:~#lspci                     (Descriptions added by me)
00:00.0 Class 0600: Device 8086:0f00 (rev 0e) Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register
00:02.0 Class 0300: Device 8086:0f31 (rev 0e) Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display
00:11.0 Class 0805: Device 8086:0f15 (rev 0e) Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SDIO Controller
00:12.0 Class 0805: Device 8086:0f16 (rev 0e) Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SDIO Controller
00:13.0 Class 0106: Device 8086:0f23 (rev 0e) Atom Processor E3800 Series SATA AHCI Controller
00:17.0 Class 0805: Device 8086:0f50 (rev 0e) Atom Processor E3800 Series eMMC 4.5 Controller
00:18.0 Class 0801: Device 8086:0f40 (rev 0e) Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series LPIO2 DMA Controller
00:18.1 Class 0c80: Device 8086:0f41 (rev 0e) Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series LPIO2 I2C Controller #1
00:18.2 Class 0c80: Device 8086:0f42 (rev 0e) Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series LPIO2 I2C Controller #2
00:18.3 Class 0c80: Device 8086:0f43 (rev 0e) Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series LPIO2 I2C Controller #3
00:18.4 Class 0c80: Device 8086:0f44 (rev 0e) Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series LPIO2 I2C Controller #4
00:18.5 Class 0c80: Device 8086:0f45 (rev 0e) Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series LPIO2 I2C Controller #5
00:18.6 Class 0c80: Device 8086:0f46 (rev 0e) Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series LPIO2 I2C Controller #6
00:18.7 Class 0c80: Device 8086:0f47 (rev 0e) Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series LPIO2 I2C Controller #7
00:1a.0 Class 1080: Device 8086:0f18 (rev 0e) Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine
00:1c.0 Class 0604: Device 8086:0f48 (rev 0e) Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1
00:1c.2 Class 0604: Device 8086:0f4c (rev 0e) Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 3
00:1d.0 Class 0c03: Device 8086:0f34 (rev 0e) Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB EHCI
00:1f.0 Class 0601: Device 8086:0f1c (rev 0e) Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit
00:1f.3 Class 0c05: Device 8086:0f12 (rev 0e) Atom Processor E3800 Series SMBus Controller
02:00.0 Class 0200: Device 8086:1533 (rev 03) I210 Gigabit Network Connection
```

```
root@serialnumber:~#lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:07e6 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How can I find the touchscreen hardware information?

Comment: It’s possible the touchscreen is connected over a serial port of some sort. Does the original distribution use `inputattach` anywhere?

Comment: @StephenKitt It's not a recognized command, so I don't think so.